# What's the best way to call a python script from ajax?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

What's the best way to call a python script from ajax?

Here's what I want to do:
1. Have an HTML form
2. When you click submit, it will run a script, python shell or what ever
3. The script will take several minutes, or longer, to run and write to a new log file while doing so
4. Then I want to have a form field on the screen, either on the same screen or a form action page
5. And the form field should be populated with the contents of the log, using Ajax to fetch new lines every x seconds.

What is the best way to do that?  And how would it keep track of where its at in the new log file?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Flask by defining a route to accept some arguments from the POSTed form. Inside that route you can run whatever python code you want. You could then have another route that you periodically query against using AJAX requests, that will return the current contents of the log, or the delta of the log since the last call to that route.

The flask [docs about routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing) are pretty good, and the [Flask general tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/#tutorial) could get you going in the right direction.

To get parameters from a request in flask you can use [flask.request.args](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.args). That should be everything you need.

To fetch the new data from the second endpoint, you could simply use [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).